# Android create ArrayList from months name

Tags: android, string, arraylist

I want to populate an arraylist with the names of the months. I get month in numeric format from the database. Now I want to convert the month number to month name and add to array. I've tried it, but it seems to work. I get every month with the same name.

```
int[] months = new int[count];
for(int n=0; n<count; n++) {
            c.moveToNext();     
            months[n]= c.getInt(0);

 ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i <months.length; i++) {    
                Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");                 
                cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,months[i]);
                String month_name = month_date.format(cal.getTime());

                   xVals.add(month_name);   

            }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only 12 months, can you not just hard code the months array values?

try this:

```
    ArrayList<String> months = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, i);
        String month_name = month_date.format(cal.getTime());

        months.add(month_name);
    }
```

Answer (score 19):

Easily:

```
DateFormatSymbols symbols = new DateFormatSymbols(); 
String[] monthNames = symbols.getMonths();
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html